# Validating GET Params with WTForms in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have spent a couple of days trying to get WTForms to validate my `request.args`, but I just can not get `form.validate()` to return `True`.

The idea is that I have a simple text field for user input in a WTForm as shown below.

**form.py**

```py
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    q = StringField('q',
                           validators=[])
    search = SubmitField('Search')

    def validate_q(self, q):
        if q.data not in allowed_values: #"allowed_values" is just a list I want to check against
            raise ValidationError('')
```

**search.html**

```html
<form method="GET" action="{{ url_for('finance.search') }}">
  <div class="col-9 col-md-5 p-0 m-0">
    {% if form.q.errors %} {{ form.q(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      {% for error in form.q.errors %}
      <span>{{ error }}</span> {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% else %} {{ form.q(class="form-control form-control-md") }} {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 col-md-2 p-0">
    {{ form.search(class="btn btn-md btn-dark") }}
  </div>
</form>
```

**routes.py**

```
@finance.route('/finance/search')
def search():
    form = SearchForm(request.args)
    print(form.validate()) #always gives false
```

The HTML code for the form is included on several templates and submitting the form always directs to the search route that is shown below. I tried following WTForms documentation and passed in `request.args` into the form. When I ran the `.validate()` on the object, the validate function for the `q` parameter also executed, but for some reason `.validate()` always returns `False`.

Can anyone please elaborate on why that might be? I know I can use post request, or add a custom validation function inside the route, but I want to avoid workarounds if possible.

(stack-overflow seems to use a similar type of architecture for their search `http://127.0.0.1:8000/finance/search?q=aapl&search=Search` vs `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aapl` and I want to follow that if possible.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually just figured out that the error was happening because I was not including a crsf_token in the form. The token is not needed since the its a get request, but this needs to be explicitly stated with `meta = {'csrf': False}`.

```
@finance.route('/finance/search')
def search():
    form = SearchForm(request.args, meta={'csrf': False})
    print(form.validate()) #Now gives True if validation function does not raise error
```

Comment: I spent hours looking for this answer and it was driving me crazy.  Thanks for posting!! :-D